# How to make input-appending drop-down list in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have the following page:

[image]

Where my code for the form looks like:

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="offset3 span3">

      <form class="form-horizontal" id="inputForm">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="volume">Beer Volume</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <div class="input-append">
            <input type="text" id="volume" placeholder="i.e. 16">
            <span class="add-on">oz</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="alcPercent">Alcohol</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <div class="input-append">
            <input type="text" id="alcPercent" placeholder="i.e. 6.3">
            <span class="add-on">%</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <button class="btn-large" type="button" value="CONVERT" onclick="onSubmit()">CONVERT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I'm trying to create the page so that "oz" is actually a drop-down menu, where the user can choose from "oz", "centiliters", "liters", etc.  Is there a way to do this cleanly in Bootstrap?  I see there's a "button dropdown": http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms , but when I copied in that code, I couldn't get any of the dropdown choices working.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to simulate `<select>` effect. Those dropdowns you're trying to apply are just simple dropdown menu.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob with web development/bootstrap.  Could you explain what you mean by simulate select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into Bootstrap Select https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select

With some CSS / jQuery customizing, it should work for you...

**Working example on Bootply**: http://bootply.com/60822

Answer (score 7):

Same problem here. Hate to fix basics with js or something.
Here is my fix :) :)

[bootypreview](http://www.bootply.com/JQsRmHfvzT)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Budget</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <select class="form-control" style="float: left;width: initial;">
                <option>&euro;</option>
                <option>&dollar;</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="float: left;width: initial;">
            <select class="form-control" style="float: left;width: initial;">
                <option>per job</option>
                <option>per hour</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```